# Does Scala have an efficient equivalent to F#'s Seq.tryPick function?

Tags: scala, sequence

Suppose I have a sequence `mySeq` consisting of elements of type `A` and a function `f` of type `A -> Option<B>`, and I want the first result of type `Option<B>` that is a `Some` resulting from applying `f` to all elements of the sequence, otherwise `None` if no such result was found.

In F# this is neatly handled by the [`tryPick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.trypick%5B%27t%2C%27u%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) function:

```
mySeq |> Seq.tryPick f
```

In Scala, the best way I could find is:

```
mySeq.iterator.map(f).find(_.isDefined).flatten
```

Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT: solutions that compute results for the whole list even after finding the first `isDefined` one are NOT acceptable.

EDIT:
From the comments of Bogdan Vakulenko and Jasper-M, a good alternative seems to be

```
mySeq.iterator.flatMap(f).nextOption()
```

Comment: `mySeq.flatMap(f).head`

Comment: @BogdanVakulenko Will this compute elements even after finding the first `isDefined` result? If so, it would be too inefficient.

Comment: it will, but you can use iterator to prevent it as you did: `mySeq.iterator.flatMap(f).head`

Comment: or convert ot stream: `mySeq.toStream.flatMap(f).head`

Comment: or you can just use some lazy collection for `mySeq`, so you don't have to convert it everywhere. It can be: Stream(LazyList), Iterator or View

Answer (score 2):

You can also implement it yourself:

```
@tailrec
def tryPick[A, B](fn: A => Option[B], seq: Seq[A]): Option[B] =
  seq match {
    case Nil => None // Only in case an empty sequence was passed initially
    case head +: Nil => fn(head)
    case head +: tail => fn(head) match {
      case Some(output) => Some(output)
      case None => tryPick(fn, tail)
    }
  }
```

Then use it like this:

```
scala> def myFn(int: Int) = if (int > 2) Some(int) else None
myFn: (int: Int)Option[Int]

scala> tryPick(myFn, List(1, 0, -2, 3))
res0: Option[Int] = Some(3)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for efficient plus more idiomatic; I'll probably stick to my original solution for now. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

`tryPick` is almost equivalent to `collectFirst`. Except that `collectFirst` works with a `PartialFunction`. So the closest you'll get is probably:

```
seq.collectFirst((f _).unlift) // when f is a method

seq.collectFirst(f.unlift) // when f is a function

seq.collectFirst(Function.unlift(f)) // when you're on Scala 2.12 or lower, or just like this better than the previous 2...
```

Behold:

```
scala> def f(a: Int) = {println(s"f($a)"); Option.when(a/2*2 == a)("x" * a)}
f: (a: Int)Option[String]

scala> List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).collectFirst((f _).unlift)
f(1)
f(2)
res1: Option[String] = Some(xx)
```

Answer (score 1):

`mySeq.iterator.flatMap(a => f(a)).toSeq.headOption`

Unfortunately `.toSeq` has to be called since `Iterator` doesn't have `headOption` method.

<s>But `toSeq` returns `Stream` for `Iterator` which is lazily evaluated so no unnecessary calculations happen.</s> <-- only before scala 2.13

Comment: `def tryPick[A, B](f: A => Option[B])(mySeq: Seq[A])  = mySeq.iterator.flatMap(f).headOption` doesn't compile. How do I make it compile?

Comment: `mySeq.iterator.flatMap(f).nextOption` on Scala 2.13

Comment: I wouldn't count on `toSeq` to return a `Stream`. E.g. on 2.13 it returns a `List`.

Answer (score -1):

you don't need the iterator at all you can just do

`mySeq.find(f(_).isDefined)`

Here is a test that shows that `find` works immediately without an iterator (time is in microseconds)

```
val mySeq = (1 to 10000000).toSeq

def f(int: Int): Option[Int] = {
  if (int < 5) Some(int * int) else None
}

val t1 = System.nanoTime

/* computes all elements */
val res1 = mySeq.filter(f(_).isDefined).head

val duration1 = (System.nanoTime - t1) / 1e6d
println(s"Computes all elements before $res1 in " + duration1)

val t2 = System.nanoTime

/* does not compute all elements */
val res2 = mySeq.find(f(_).isDefined).head
val duration2 = (System.nanoTime - t2) / 1e6d
println(s"Returns $res2 immediately after " + duration2)
```

**Result**

```
Computes all elements before 1 in 143.293762
Returns 1 immediately after 1.192212
```

Comment: What??? If the very first result is a `None` then I don't want it. Why would I call `.head` on it?
In any case, if this computes elements even after finding the first isDefined result, then it would be too inefficient for my purposes.

Comment: I thought i was pretty clear but I guess not so I revised the answer.  Did that help?

Comment: Afraid not - 1) your `head` should be a `headOption` anyways and 2) I want ONLY the first result computed and short-circuited.

Comment: Well I was a little confused by the wording in your question I guess but it's better now that you edited it.  Anyway I would do this with pattern matching so I made quick example for you in the revised answer.

Comment: You still don't need an iterator man you can just `mySeq.find(f(_)  != None)`

Comment: No. This will return the elements of the sequence, not the result of applying f. Now you will have to recompute the application of f.

Comment: You can just map the function again man the average runtime complexity is still not O(n) `mySeq.find(f(_).isDefined).map(f)`

Comment: Look "man", I don't want to compute `f` twice if I don't have to.